# Should there be a tag for closed questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

I was thinking it might be good to have a way to pull up a list of closed questions.  I'm assuming mods can do this, but it might be good even for newcomers, kind of like that "breadcrumb" thing mentioned in the editing question.  It would allow someone to see what kinds of questions tend to get closed.

I'm not sure if closed questions get auto-deleted after a time, though, in which case my question is moot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for [closed:1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1) ;)

See [Search Options on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).